# Why do I not get a link error if I use extern template class with just one translation unit?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, linker

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
class X
{
public:
    T t;

    void func1() { std::cout << "Test"; }
    void func2(T x) { }
};

extern template class X<int>;

int main()
{
    X<int> x;
    x.func1();
}
```

This code compiles and links correctly ([live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/309a2522f7b6fbaf)).

However, I cannot understand why I don't get a link error due to the `extern template class` declaration. According to [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template#Explicit_instantiation) (emphasis mine):

> An explicit instantiation declaration (an extern template) skips
>   implicit instantiation step: **the code that would otherwise cause an
>   implicit instantiation instead uses the explicit instantiation
>   definition provided elsewhere** (resulting in link errors if no such
>   instantiation exists). This can be used to reduce compilation times by
>   explicitly declaring a template instantiation in all but one of the
>   source files using it, and explicitly defining it in the remaining
>   file.

As far as I understand, the `extern template class` declaration should prevent the compiler from implicitly instantiating X with `T = int` in `main`. Because no instantiation actually exists, this should result in link-time errors.

Why does this code link?

Comment: I'm getting a linker error with both gcc and clang, see e.g. this [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/868fb3fdb2ac6ad7). What compiler are you using?

Comment: @vsoftco Tested on both VC++ 14.0 and Coliru (g++, see link in question).

Comment: It looks like passing `-O2` makes the linker happy, have no idea why. If you remove `-O2`, you'll get a linker error. What optimization has to do with it I've no idea.

Comment: What does "elsewhere" mean? Must it mean "a different translation unit"?

Comment: @vsoftco Strange, we're both using the same platform with different results... in my case `-O2` was used, could that matter? (compare http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/309a2522f7b6fbaf vs http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/868fb3fdb2ac6ad7)

Comment: @szczurcio Yes it looks like, same behaviour for clang. However I believe you should get a linker error, as you mentioned.

Comment: I'd guess that with -O2, the compiler "looks through" all the template "stuff" and sees that in the end, you're just printing "Test", regardless of the template's parameter, so it just generates code for that, without ever actually creating an object, so the fact that you're telling it to use an instantiation that doesn't exist becomes irrelevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in the comments, the linker error is present with `-O0` but goes away with `-O2`.  When you have an explicit instantiation declaration, the compiler gets to assume the best of both worlds: the definition is available, so if the compiler feels like inlining it, it can.  But if the compiler doesn't feel like inlining it, it can assume the actual function will be generated in another translation unit.  So you only notice the promise to explicitly instantiate it is broken if the compiler decides not to inline the function.

Answer (score 1):

This error is a One Definition Rule violation, in the form of there being zero definitions when one is required.

The reason the code runs is that the compiler optimized `X<int> x; x.func1();` to `std::cout << "Test";`, which is allowed because the observable behaviour is the same.

This sort of error is *undefined behaviour with no diagnostic required*. The reason that the standard does not require a diagnostic is that it would complicate the compilation model.  To have the linker produce a diagnostic for this code, the object file would have to contain extra symbols to link-check even though those symbols were not actually used in the object file.

Here is a simpler program with the same behaviour for the same reason:

```
void f(); int main() { int x = 0; if (x) f(); }
```